# Trouble reading next line from a file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm trying to make a C++ program which finds a specific line in a text file and then reads the next 3 line of that file. But the program is ending up showing the same line three times.What could be a possible fix for this? Here is my code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("file.txt");
    string line;
    int iffound=0;
    string inp;

    cin>>inp;
    cout << "You have searched for " << inp << endl;

    while (file.good())
    {
        getline(file,line);
        if(line==inp){
            iffound=1;
            cout << "Contact Found!" << endl;
            for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
                cout << line;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    file.close();

    if(iffound!=1){
        cout << "Contact Not Found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my text file (file.txt)

```
123456
User1
Available
Active

789456
User2
Not Available
Active
```

Comment: Well, after you found your line, you have a for loop that prints the same variable, over and over again. A computer will always do exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do, unfortunately.

Comment: [FYI] Do not use `while (file.good())`.  It is just  like `while (file.eof())`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: what should I use instead of **while (file.good())** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop does no more reading, it just prints it 3 times:

```
                 for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
                    cout << line;
                 }
```

If you want the code to keep reading more lines, you need to put the reading inside that loop too:

```
                 for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
                    getline(file,line);
                    cout << line;
                 }
```

Comment: An example will help me understand better

Comment: replacing my code with 
`for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
                    getline(file,line);
                    cout << line <<endl;
                 }`
works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you are not reading the following two lines with `getline` if you found your occurence. Basically, you are missing the `getline` in your `for`

Comment: I used `for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
                    getline(file,line);
                    cout << line;
                 }` and now working fine. Thanks! :)